# Exchange Web service (EWS) chain FindItemType for itemItemclas & messageIsRead

Tags: vb.net, ssis, exchangewebservices

High fellow coders.

I'm using the raw exchange web service, referenced in my SSIS script task.

My issue is that when I enumerate items in a mailbox or folder, Not only am I interested in only those items that have not been read, but I want to ignore all the system type messages. so I only want items, specifically messages, who's "itemclass" is "IPM.Note" nothing else.

Here is a definitive list of Item Types and Message classes
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861573.aspx

my code which works successfully for unread items in the inbox

```
 'declare my find criteria, return only the IDs, from the inbox, for unread items
    Dim reqFindUnreadMailInInbox As FindItemType = New FindItemType With _
    {.Traversal = ItemQueryTraversalType.Shallow _
     , .ItemShape = New ItemResponseShapeType With {.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.IdOnly} _
     , .ParentFolderIds = New DistinguishedFolderIdType(0) {New DistinguishedFolderIdType With {.Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.inbox}} _
     , .Restriction = New RestrictionType With _
        {.Item = New IsEqualToType With _
        {.Item = New PathToUnindexedFieldType With {.FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.messageIsRead} _
                                                    , .FieldURIOrConstant = New FieldURIOrConstantType With {.Item = New ConstantValueType With {.Value = "0"}} _
                                                } _
        } _
    }

    'go fetch the response from exchange
    Dim resFindItemResponse As FindItemResponseType = esb.FindItem(reqFindUnreadMailInInbox)
    Dim resFindFolderMessages As FindItemResponseMessageType = resFindItemResponse.ResponseMessages.Items(0)
    Dim resFolderItems As ArrayOfRealItemsType = Nothing '= New ArrayOfRealItemsType
```

The problem I have is I want to add a restriction on the itemClass that is returned. But cannot figure out how to add a second Restriction to the request. This is what the restriction would look like if I changed my search to pull all items from the inbox regardless of read state but restricting only to itemClass IPM.Note *(note the addition of the paged result)*

```
 Dim reqFindUnreadMailInInbox As FindItemType = New FindItemType With _
   {.Item = New IndexedPageViewType With {.MaxEntriesReturnedSpecified = True, .MaxEntriesReturned = "100", .BasePoint = IndexBasePointType.Beginning, .Offset = 0} _
    , .Traversal = ItemQueryTraversalType.Shallow _
    , .ItemShape = New ItemResponseShapeType With {.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.IdOnly} _
    , .ParentFolderIds = New DistinguishedFolderIdType(0) {New DistinguishedFolderIdType With {.Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.inbox}} _
    , .Restriction = New RestrictionType With _
       {.Item = New IsEqualToType With _
                                   {.Item = New PathToUnindexedFieldType With {.FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.itemItemClass} _
                                                , .FieldURIOrConstant = New FieldURIOrConstantType With {.Item = New ConstantValueType With {.Value = "IPM.Note"}} _
                                   } _
       } _
   }
```

The next chunk of code checks for an error, and proceeds to enumerate the IDs and fetch the items in one call. If I debug the resGetitem after the response has returned, I can drill down and look at each items class by looking in the immediate window with this query

```
?directcast(directcast(resGetItem.ResponseMessages.Items(0),ItemInfoResponseMessageType).Items.Items(0),MessageType)
```

and I can see "REPORTS.IPM.Note.NDR". The question is how can I filter the initial call to restrict to only "IPM.Note"

```
 'if there was an error bur out and report
    If resFindFolderMessages.ResponseClass = ResponseClassType.[Error] Then
        Throw New Exception(resFindFolderMessages.MessageText)
    Else
        TraceLog.AppendLine("Inbox found, ID pulled back")
        If Not IsNothing(DirectCast(resFindFolderMessages.RootFolder.Item, ArrayOfRealItemsType).Items) Then
            resFolderItems = resFindFolderMessages.RootFolder.Item
            TraceLog.AppendLine(String.Format("found {0} unread mail - start processing", resFolderItems.Items.Count))
            'So we have the array of ids for the emails, now fetch the emails themselves
            Dim resItemIDs As ItemIdType() = Nothing
            'collect the ids up
            For x As Integer = 0 To resFolderItems.Items.Count - 1
                If IsNothing(resItemIDs) Then ReDim resItemIDs(0) Else ReDim Preserve resItemIDs(resItemIDs.Length)
                resItemIDs(x) = resFolderItems.Items(x).ItemId
            Next
            'go get the email messages
            Dim resGetItem As GetItemResponseType = esb.GetItem(New GetItemType With { _
                                                                .ItemShape = New ItemResponseShapeType With {.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.AllProperties _
                                                                                                             , .BodyType = BodyTypeResponseType.Text _
                                                                                                             , .BodyTypeSpecified = True} _
                                                                , .ItemIds = resItemIDs})
            'declare and fill up the message array that we are going to return
            Dim resItemMessage As ItemType() = Nothing
            For x As Integer = 0 To resGetItem.ResponseMessages.Items.Length - 1
                If IsNothing(resItemMessage) Then ReDim resItemMessage(0) Else ReDim Preserve resItemMessage(resItemMessage.Length)
                resItemMessage(x) = DirectCast(resGetItem.ResponseMessages.Items(x), ItemInfoResponseMessageType).Items.Items(0)
            Next
            'pass back the emails
            Return resItemMessage
        Else
            TraceLog.AppendLine("no unread mail found closing out")
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End If
```

========== UPDATE ============

With a nudge in the right direction from Glen Scales we have Success! EWS is a mine field of types and derived types.

```
'create the finditemtype and load the restrictions
    'first only the unread messages
    'secondly, only of type "IPM.Note" ie just emails
    Dim reqFindUnreadMailInInbox As FindItemType = New FindItemType With _
    {.Traversal = ItemQueryTraversalType.Shallow _
     , .ItemShape = New ItemResponseShapeType With {.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.IdOnly} _
     , .ParentFolderIds = New DistinguishedFolderIdType(0) {New DistinguishedFolderIdType With {.Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.inbox}} _
     , .Restriction = New RestrictionType With {.Item = New AndType With { _
    .Items = New IsEqualToType() { _
     New IsEqualToType With {.Item = New PathToUnindexedFieldType With { _
                              .FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.messageIsRead} _
                            , .FieldURIOrConstant = New FieldURIOrConstantType With {.Item = New ConstantValueType With {.Value = "0"}} _
                            } _
     , New IsEqualToType With {.Item = New PathToUnindexedFieldType With { _
                               .FieldURI = UnindexedFieldURIType.itemItemClass} _
                                , .FieldURIOrConstant = New FieldURIOrConstantType With {.Item = New ConstantValueType With {.Value = "IPM.Note"}} _
                                } _
    }}}}
```

Thanks goes to Glen Scales!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the AndType https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/exchangewebservices.andtype(v=exchg.150).aspx

Then define and add two isEqual Restrictions to that eg

```
RestrictionType restriction = new RestrictionType();
AndType andType = new AndType();
andType.Items = new SearchExpressionType[] { IsEqual1,IsEqual2 };
restriction.Item = andType;
```

Cheers
Glen